# HTML 5 Boilerplate HTACCESS Stopping my mod_rewrite from working

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm using HTML5 BP's [.htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) file unedited. Everything works fine until I add my own rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+-?[a-z]+)/$ /$1.php
```

this works fine if add it to it's own `.htaccess` file (after starting the engine and adding options) but does not when added to the html5 BP's file . I've tried placing it all over the document, inside the if tags, top of the doc and bottom.

I'd like the rewrite to load mydomain.com/example.php when a user inputs mydomain.com/example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That expression won't match `/example`:

You've got the `/` on the end, not the beginning as you have in your replacement string.  Given that it's in `.htaccess`, and assuming that `example.php` is in the same directory as this `.htaccess` file, then you don't want slashes at all.  Clarify if this is not the case.  And if you have access to the server config, then don't use `.htaccess`, period.

You've got the `-` as optional, but then you're forcing another one-or-more match of alphabetical characters, and you're forcing lower-case.  This is far more complicated than it needs to be; how about this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Sorry I missed typed how it should work . I want when a user inputs mydomain.com/example then apache will load mydomain.com/example.php . I really want to use this for a blog system where the variable will be placed in the url variables .

Comment: @FrankAstin The rule that I've provided above *will* rewrite `/example` to `/example.php`, assuming that the `.htaccess` file is located directly in the `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Yeah it's in the root : Just tried it without the html5BP and it works as expected . So it's definitely something to do with placement in the H5BP htaccess ...

Comment: @FrankAstin Well, with a quick glance at that file I'm not seeing anything that should conflict.. but, try putting your rules immediately under the `RewriteEngine On` line in that file, and add a `[L]` to the end of the `RewriteRule` line.